# Why is httpd hanging when trying to start?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

When I try to start HTTPD, it begins with:

```
    Starting HTTPD
    httpd (pid 32303) already running
    Starting SSH tunnels
    Starting HTTPD
    httpd (pid 32615) already running
    Starting SSH tunnels
```

It then just hangs for quite sometime. I've tried to tail the error_log, but the error log doesn't seem to update. The logs are all old.

Where do I go from here? I haven't been able to find much about HTTPD hanging when trying to start.

Any direction would be awesome. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I'm trying to start httpd using an instance, so I start it by: 
        /sbin/service ptst str

I'm pretty sure it was installed by package manager and it's RedHat 7.

UPDATE:

I killed processes 32303 and 32615 so when I start httpd nothing is already running but it still hangs. I tailed my error log using sudo tail -f /opt/logs/error_log and it hangs and shows:

```
    [Tue Aug 27 14:29:22.022047 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1817:tid                         
    140076146927424] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/apache-2.4.37/bin/httpd -f 
    /opt/conf/httpd.conf'
    [Wed Aug 28 09:44:53.318939 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1817:tid 
    140076146927424] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed Aug 28 10:09:33.886272 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3205:tid  
    139902668130112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips 
    configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed Aug 28 10:09:33.886543 2019] [core:notice] [pid 3205:tid 
    139902668130112] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/apache-2.4.37/bin/httpd -f 
    /opt/conf/httpd.conf'
    [Wed Aug 28 10:36:40.245765 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3205:tid 
    139902668130112] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed Aug 28 10:37:21.693187 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5687:tid 
    140062877488960] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips 
    configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed Aug 28 10:37:21.693447 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5687:tid 
    140062877488960] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/apache-2.4.37/bin/httpd -f 
    /opt/conf/httpd.conf'
    [Wed Aug 28 10:46:07.234149 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5687:tid 
    140062877488960] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed Aug 28 10:46:55.445671 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6452:tid 
    140204271298368] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips 
    configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed Aug 28 10:46:55.445820 2019] [core:notice] [pid 6452:tid 
    140204271298368] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/apache-2.4.37/bin/httpd -f 
    /opt/conf/httpd.conf'
```

When I sudo tail -f /var/log/messages, it hangs and shows:

```
    fostunnel: d'utiliser le systeme, le client affirme qu'il est un client                 
    autorise.
    dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' 
    (using servicehelper)
    dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 
    'org.freedesktop.problems'
    su: (to fostunnel) MC on pts/1
    su: (to fostunnel) MC on pts/1
    systemd: Stopping SYSV: Start up the Apache HTTPD server....
    apache: Stopping HTTPD
    systemd: Stopped SYSV: Start up the Apache HTTPD server..
    su: (to fostunnel) MC on pts/1
    su: (to fostunnel) MC on pts/1
    systemd: Reloading.
    systemd: Started Flexible Branding Service.
    systemd: Starting SYSV: Start up the Apache HTTPD server....
    apache: Starting HTTPD
    systemd: Started SYSV: Start up the Apache HTTPD server..
```

Comment: You should provide some more information. your question is unclear.

Comment: What command did you use to start it? How is/was it installed (manually or via a package manager)? What Linux distribution are you using? Why does your output have "Starting SSH tunnels" in it?

Comment: i could not find any `ptst` HTTP service within RedHat repositories so more information on what your `ptst` script is would be needed to assist.  How it was installed or the project name others can find it under could also help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my ptst script didn't end when httpd started - it was in a loop. I tested my instances and httpd did in fact start successfully.